# Confusion with type inference of literals in Go

Tags: go, types, type-inference

I have started learning GoLang and I am currently reading about its type inference system using the short variable declaration syntax.

Here is a simple program that caught my attention and is causing me some diffculty in understanding:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

type statistics struct {
    numbers []float64
    mean    float64
    median  float64
}

// Performs analytics on a slice of floating-point numbers
func GenerateStats(numbers []float64) (stats statistics) {
    stats.numbers = numbers
    stats.mean = sum(numbers) / float64(len(numbers))
    sort.Float64s(numbers)
    stats.median = median(numbers)
    return stats
}

// Helper function to sum up a slice of floats
func sum(numbers []float64) (total float64) {
    for _, num := range numbers {
        total += num
    }
    return total
}

// Helper to find the median of a sorted slice of floats
func median(numbers []float64) (med float64) {
    n := len(numbers)
    if n%2 == 0 {
        med = numbers[n/2]
    } else {
        med = (numbers[n/2] + numbers[(n-1)/2]) / 2 // Infer 01
    }
    return med
}

func main() {
    nums := []float64{1, 2, 3, 3, 4}
    result := generateStats(nums)
    fmt.Println(result.numbers)
    fmt.Println(result.mean)
    fmt.Println(result.median)

    b := "This is Go" + 1.9 // Infer 02
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

When I execute this program using: `$ go run <path>/statistics.go`,
I get the following error message:

```
# command-line-arguments
<path>/statistics.go:47:20: cannot convert "This is Go" to type float64
<path>/statistics.go:47:20: invalid operation: "This is Go" + 1.9 (mismatched types string and float64)
```

Here is reasoning for the different behavious:

`Infer 01`: The type of numeric literal `2` is inferred on the basis of the expression it is used in. Since the type of numerator is `float64`, Go performs the division successfully by assuming `2` as of the corresponding type. Hence, the type of the variable on LHS is `float64`.

I used the same reasoning for `Infer 02`:
The type of float literal `1.9` is inferred on the basis of the declaration. However, a float literal cannot be added to a string unless it is implicitly converted to a string. So, I am unsure about the type of the variable `b`. Hence, an error should be raised.

Now, I am confused by the error message.

Why does the compiler try to implicitly convert string literal to `float64` type?

In a general sense: How does the compiler infer types when both the operands are literals? What are some good resources that can help me understand Go's type inference system better?

Comment: Go infers types for literals only really for numerical constants, and then only for numerical types (variants and aliases of `int` and `float`).  Also note that quotes explicitly mark a literal as a string, there's no type inference needed or done.

Comment: What makes Go special here is how _constants_ are treated (your literals). They behave basically totally different then in other languages. Read in Go's blog https://blog.golang.org/constants about constants and their default type. (It really isn't much about type inference. 2 is a constant int, 1.9 a constant float and "foo" a constant string. Note the constant!)

Comment: You are confused because you are using Kshitij reasoning. Use Go reasoning: The Go Programming Language Specification : https://golang.org/ref/spec

Answer (score 2):

It does not try to convert it to `float64` type. It just warns about the string literal not being of `float64`.

It could say either the string is not a float, or the float is not a string, but the second line covers both of the cases with the message `mismatched types string and float64`.

Answer (score 1):

Literal and constants in Go does not have a Go type. For example:

- think of `1.1234` as float constant (and not a `float32` or `float64`)
- `2` as an int constant
- `"hi"` as a string constant.

When you try to put a constant inside a variable Go tries to fit the constant in the variable based on variable type:

```
type DayCount int
const i = 123456

var a int32 = i
var b uint64 = i
var c int = i
var d int8 = i  // compile error: constant 123456 overflows int8
var e DayCount = i
var f DayCount = c  // compile error: cannot use c (type int) as type DayCount in assignment
```

If the variable itself doesn't have a type and the right hand side of assignment is a constant, compiler will assume the "default type" of the constant. That is `int` type for int constants and `float64` for float constants.

```
var a = 1234          // a type will be int
var b = 1.1234567890  // b type will be float64
var c = "gogogo"      // c type will be string
```

You could also do some operations on constants (before they are converted to normal go variable) that is done in compile time:

```
var a int8 = 25 * 87  // compile error: constant 2175 overflows int8
```

As both 25 and 87 are constants compiler will multiple them when your are compiling your program and tries to fit it into variable `a` that fails. The point is multiply is not done when you are running your program.

If you try to mix normal variables and constants, compiler will try to convert constants to your variables type:

```
var a uint64 = 87
var b = 25 * a
// Is the same as
var b = uint64(25) * a
// so b type is uint64
```

Now about the first case in your question

```
med = (numbers[n/2] + numbers[(n-1)/2]) / 2 // Infer 01
```

is the same as

```
med = (numbers[n/int(2)] + numbers[(n-int(1))/int(2)]) / float64(2)
```

Compiler will try to cast constant into nearby variable type. The first and second `2` is being used in a division operation with an `int` and are converted to `int`. The third one is used in a division with a `float64` and converted to `float64`. I don't think "type inference" is a fitting name for here.

In the second case both `+` operators are constants, compiler uses a heuristic approach and assumes that if one of the constants is float both constants should be fit into a `float64` (that is faulty) and tries to put a string constant into `float64` that fails (Hence the can't convert to `float64` error).

The second case behavior is not documented in spec and I don't think it matters at all. IMO a valid compiler may try to fit `1.9` into a string variable and shows another error.

See also [blog on constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants), [spec on constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants), [spec on constants expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).